# Why Xubuntu is damaging my headphone but it is working fine with Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, hardware

After installing Xubuntu 16.04, 3 headphones got damaged. I plugged the headphones into the headphone socket and within minutes the left ear side of headphone stopped working.

After reverting back to Ubuntu 16.04 everything is working fine again. No new headphones get damaged any more. (The damaged headphones remain as it is.)

Also bluetooth is not working in Xubuntu but working in Ubuntu. Likewise I am facing many other hardware issues in Xubuntu but not in Ubuntu.

Why is this happening?

I am using Acer laptop with configuration :

- AMD Quad-Core Processor A4-7210(up to 2.2 GHz)
- AMD Radeon<sup>TM</sup> R3 Graphics
- 4GB DDR3 L Memory
- 1000 GB HDD

Comment: What version of Ubuntu ? Xubuntu ? what kernel in each ?

Comment: Xubuntu 16.04 latest, Ubuntu 16.04 latest

Comment: So the headphone is not damaged,  works fine in ubuntu?

Comment: OMG, I have clearly written in the question that, "No new headphones get damaged any more." It means damaged headphones remain as it is.

Comment: It is possible, likely even, then that the broken headphone had nothing to do with Ubuntu . At any rate we need more information and generally one question at a time. Try to work through https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingBluetooth or similar

Comment: In short my new headphone breaks down when in Xubuntu and remains as it is whether it is in Ubuntu, Windows or Mac. But another new headphone does not break down if the OS is Ubuntu and not Xubuntu. So where is the confusion?